# Importing data from MS Excel to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, excel, data-import

I've a Microsoft Excel file with 25 columns and I used the data import wizard on SQL Server 2008 R2 studio to import it to already existing table. But, it only maps 14 columns and ignores the rest. Does it have a column number limit or there is a problem with my data?

Answer (score 1):

Can you give some example of your data?

In the mean time... When you're performing your import, I assume you are reaching the `Select Source Tables and Views` Page;

[image]

At this stage, you can edit your column mappings by pressing the `Edit Mappings` button. This will show the following screen;

[image]

Make sure that all your columns are selected there.

Also, on the following screen, it will warn of any mismatches in data;

[image]

Are you seeing any warnings here?

Comment: Thanks but only few of the columns are listed in the Edit Mappings. Is there any way to add the rest of the columns?

Comment: Hi Aby... can you take a screenshot of your top rows of data, including the column names, and add it to your original post? Or list out your columns and some example data? I can perhaps see if there's something ary?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar much with SQL Server, but according to this: [Excel file Import to Sql server 2008](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/a7d6aeea-3df8-4d31-bdc1-b5e968e6759e/) - column limit for Excel is **255** which is far beyond your numbers. Most likely problem is in your data, but without having the example it's impossible to say what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the other way around.

Step 1. **[Import sheet in a new table.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123113/how-to-import-an-excel-file-into-sqlserver-2008)**

Step 2. **[Use Bulk Query to insert into your prefered table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74162/how-to-do-insert-into-a-table-records-extracted-from-another-table)**

I think this will solve your **Problem**.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the Excel columns and table structure in the same format and structure as ms sql table is. Open the excel select the row (whole row by clicking on row number) select the whole data till end of the data (selected first row to last row). press ctrl+c

edit the ms sql table, go to last row where you can find blank.

Select that row by clicking on row button and press ctrl+v.

Done you're excel data will be inserted into sql table.

I tried it in MS SQL 2008