# How do I import an Excel spreadsheet into SQL Server 2008R2 database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, import-from-excel

I have got huge list of contact information in an Excel sheet that I would like to turn into table in the database so that I can maintain them in the database.

I tried following the import/export flat file import from the SQL Server 2008 R2, but it did not work. Can anyone tell me how do I successfully import the spreadsheet into a table in the database?

Thanks

Comment: In the import, you need to choose Excel File and not Flat File. Either that or convert your source file to a CSV and then use flat file in your import.

Comment: Also, note that if you're using the `Import and Export Data` option from the SQL Server start menu group, you will have to use the 32-bit version, as the excel provider does not work with 64-bit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to import an excel file into sqlserver 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123113/how-to-import-an-excel-file-into-sqlserver-2008)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a microsoft knowledge base article that lays out all the ways this is possible.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321686

I think using OPENROWSET or OPENDATASOURCE will be the easiest way, without the wizard. (see Distributed Queries)

```
SELECT * INTO XLImport4 FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\test\xltest.xls', [Customers$])
```

See OPENROWSET documentation, with examples lower down the page.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx

Manually

Right click on the database name/go to task and then select import data, as a source select an excel file that you created before and choose it's path on the next page select sql server as destination