# Read csv/xsls file and insert in SQL 2008 database table with ColdFusion 2016?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, coldfusion, sql-insert, cfloop

I have `.csv` file with about 80k records. File has about 15 columns but I need only 3 for my insert purpose. First I use ColdFusion cfhttp method to read the file from my server, then I tried to use this technique to insert multiple rows in SQL database table. Here is example:

```
<cfsetting requestTimeOut = "36000" />
<cfhttp method="get" url="https://testsite.org/ZipCodes.csv" name="zipData">  

<cfquery name="qryZip" datasource="testDB">
    INSERT INTO ZipCodes(
        z_zip,
        z_city,
        z_state
    )VALUES
    <cfloop query="zipData">
    (
        <cfqueryparam value="#trim(zipData.ZipCode)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_char" maxlength="5">,
        <cfqueryparam value="#trim(zipData.City)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="50">,
        <cfqueryparam value="#trim(zipData.State)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_char" maxlength="2">
    )
    </cfloop>
</cfquery>
```

Code above just keeps loading forever and I still did not get results in my table. Then I tried to do this:

```
<cfloop query="zipData">
    <cfquery name="qryZip" datasource="testDB">
        INSERT INTO ZipCodes(
            z_zip,
            z_city,
            z_state
        )VALUES

        (
            <cfqueryparam value="#trim(zipData.ZipCode)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_char" maxlength="5">,
            <cfqueryparam value="#trim(zipData.City)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="50">,
            <cfqueryparam value="#trim(zipData.State)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_char" maxlength="2">
        )
    </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

This method works but in my opinion is very inefficient since I'm opening new database connection for each record, instead first solution should be way more efficient. There is 80k records in this file and process should be fast but instead my first solution takes forever. Is there something that I'm doing wrong or there is some other problem with this method? If anyone knows how to get this solution to work or some other better approach please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: If it's well formed, I'd download the file, [BULK INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22301361/8895292) it into a temp table. Then validate and insert whatever columns you need into the destination table.

Comment: I highly recommend looking into BULK INSERT too.  I've had to create a temporary view in order to avoid having to specifically deal with certain data types, but VARCHAR fields don't require any extra effort.  Bulk imports are processed in milleseconds versus the multiple seconds (and potential timeout) that you may encounter when looping. We transfer the CSV file to the SQL server and perform a local import using UNC path.  It's very, very fast and hasn't ever had any issues.

Comment: I ended up using BULK INSERT and was pretty easy since I specified only columns that I need from the file. Thank you all for help.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  Since there's already a similar answer, flagging as dupe of [How to make batch insert with ColdFusion having more than 1000 records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22300600/how-to-make-batch-insert-with-coldfusion-having-more-than-1000-records)

Answer (score 3):

In your first code snippet, you're missing the comma between iterations.  As you can see, you were on the right track in your original attempt as explained here.  However, this article also warns of data locking, query buffer overflow, max param limit.

https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2017/11/bulk-inserting-data/

Also, while testing, I'd add an `endrow` parameter to your `<cfloop>` to a relatively small number just to see if the resultant code is syntactically and programmatically sound.

```
<cfsetting requestTimeOut = "36000" />
<cfhttp method="get" url="https://testsite.org/ZipCodes.csv" name="zipData">  

<cfquery name="qryZip" datasource="testDB">
    INSERT INTO ZipCodes(
        z_zip,
        z_city,
        z_state
    )VALUES
    <cfloop query="zipData">
    <cfif currentRow NEQ 1>,</cfif>
    (
        <cfqueryparam value="#trim(zipData.ZipCode)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_char" maxlength="5">,
        <cfqueryparam value="#trim(zipData.City)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="50">,
        <cfqueryparam value="#trim(zipData.State)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_char" maxlength="2">
    )
    </cfloop>
</cfquery>
```

Comment: The max param limit, ~2100 for sql server, is not emphasized strongly enough.  If you have to use ColdFusion as opposed to better tools, suck it up and do the individual inserts one row at a time.

Comment: @DanBracuk Seems like that is the only solution with ColdFusion so far. Thank you.