# How to insert more than 1000 record at a time without using BULK insert in ColdFusion?

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am reading a spreadsheet which is having 2400 rows. I want to insert all these records to a SQL server table. My client does not want to use bulk insert. Where as batch insert only allows 1000 records at a time.

Anyone please suggest how can I do this?

Comment: Just to be clear, SSIS is not an option?

Comment: No , I just want to do it using simple sql.

Comment: Sigh, if you had searched the site, you would have found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22300600/how-to-make-batch-insert-with-coldfusion-having-more-than-1000-records/22301361#22301361

Comment: @Jarede the question states - "without bulk insert"

Comment: Am I and @Leigh the only ones who read that answer in full?

Comment: You could read the spreadsheet into a query and then loop through said query inserting rows one by one.  It's inefficient, but it works.  As far as the client specifying that you not use bulk insert, you should ask yourself why you are even discussing that level of detail with your client.

Comment: *does not want to use bulk insert.* Why not? Tools like bulk insert and [`openrowset`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21732069/how-do-i-import-an-excel-spreadsheet-into-sql-server-2008r2-database) are designed specifically for this task. If you absolutely must loop, see @Jarede 's link. The last paragraph  explains how to construct the necessary logic. But again, I am curious as to why you do not wish to use the tools at your disposal.

Comment: Jarede, if an answer contains multiple options, highlight them in some way (headers/hrs/whatever). Whilst someone asking a question should certainly read entire answers, it's not unexpected for someone following a link to think _you're_ the one not doing the reading when the other info is buried in what looks like a closing paragraph.

Comment: fair enough @PeterBoughton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO   


 Insert into [TABLE]
        select * FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
        'Data Source=C:\test.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0')...[Sheat1$]
```